# AR Foundation / ARCore / ARKit fiducial markers generation

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, arkit, arcore

I am trying to develop an AR application in unity using the new AR Foundation.

This application would need to use two features:

- It needs to use a large amount of tracking images
- It needs to properly identify the tracked image (marker) (Only one image will be visible at the same moment)

What I need is dynamically generate the fiducial markers preferably with the tracking part same for all and only with specific part carrying id of the marker. Preferably the AR code would be similar to the ARToolkit One from this image:

[image]

Do these markers work well with ARfoundation (abstraction over ARCore and ARKit)?
Lets say I ll add 100 of these generated codes into the XRImageIs it possible that AR Foundation image targets get "confused" and mixup tracked images? Could in theory i use QR codes as Markers and simply code ID information into the QR code?

Answer (score 3):

In a project I searched for a good way to implement a lot of different markers to identify a vast amount of different real world objects. At first I tried QRCodes and added them to the Image Database in ARFoundation.

It worked but sometimes markers got mixed up and this already happened by using only 4 QRCodes containing words ("left", "right", "up", "down"). The problem was that ARFoundation relies on ARCore, ARKit, etc. (Depending on the platform you want to build.)

Excerpt from the ARCore guide:

> [Avoid images with that contain a large number of geometric features, or very few features (e.g. barcodes, QR codes, logos and other line art) as this will result in poor detection and tracking performance.](https://developers.google.com/ar/develop/java/augmented-images/)

The next thing I tried was to combine OpenCV with ARFoundation and use ArUco Marker for detection. The detection works much better and faster than the Image Recognition. This was done by accessing the Camera Image and using OpenCVs marker detection. In ARFoundation you can access the camera image by using [`public bool TryAcquireLatestCpuImage(out XRCpuImage cpuImage)`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.xr.arfoundation@4.0/manual/cpu-camera-image.html).

The Problem of this method:

> [This is a resource-intensive process that impacts performance](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.xr.arfoundation@4.0/manual/cpu-camera-image.html)...

On an iPad Pro 13" 2020, the performance in my application dropped from constant 60 FPS to around 25 FPS. For me, this was a too serious performance drop.

A solution could be to create a collection of images with large variations and perfect score, but I am unsure how images with all these aspects in mind could be generated. (Probably also limited to 1000 images per reference database, [see ARCore guide](https://developers.google.com/ar/develop/java/augmented-images/guide))

Comment: Well, sir, your observation and progress were very similar to my own with sadly similar results. I don't know how to generate these markers universally for AR foundation (Both ARCore and ARKit)

Comment: I'm currently building a wayfinding system inside a building using ARfoundation + QR (Zxing.dll) codes. I have a problem that the QR code is not recognized well while using ARFoundation + QR.
Can I improve the recognition rate?
 Can you give me a little help?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to check if these markers works well in ARCore , goto this [link](https://developers.google.com/ar/develop/c/augmented-images/arcoreimg) and download the arcoreimg tool.

The tool will give you a score that will let you know if this image is trackable or not. Though site recommends the score to be 75 , i have tested this for score of as low as 15. Here is quick [demo](https://youtu.be/6Ct2Cb71Wf0?t=190) if you are interested to see. The router image in the demo has a score of 15.